# Joomla Unknown column JReviews

Tags: mysql, joomla

I've transfered a JReviews database from a previous Joomla site and am having some real trouble getting the database to talk to the plugin.

One of three error pages listed here. I'm getting good at MySQL but it's a real mess and more of a pizzle if anyone can see a easy fix would really appreciate it!

Unknown column 'Totals.media_count' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT Listing.id AS `Listing.listing_id`, Listing.alias AS `Listing.slug`, Listing.title AS `Listing.title`, Listing.introtext AS `Listing.summary`, Listing.fulltext AS `Listing.description`, Listing.images AS `Listing.images`, Listing.hits AS `Listing.hits`, Listing.catid AS `Listing.cat_id`, Listing.created_by AS `Listing.user_id`, Listing.created_by_alias AS `Listing.author_alias`, Listing.created AS `Listing.created`, Listing.modified AS `Listing.modified`, Listing.access AS `Listing.access`, Listing.state AS `Listing.state`, Listing.publish_up AS `Listing.publish_up`, Listing.publish_down AS `Listing.publish_down`, Listing.metakey AS `Listing.metakey`, Listing.metadesc AS `Listing.metadesc`, 'com_content' AS `Listing.extension`, Field.featured AS `Listing.featured`, JreviewsCategory.criteriaid AS `Listing.listing_type_id`, Category.id AS `Category.cat_id`, Category.title AS `Category.title`, Category.alias AS `Category.slug`, Category.params AS `Category.params`, Directory.id AS `Directory.dir_id`, Directory.desc AS `Directory.title`, Directory.title AS `Directory.slug`, User.id AS `User.user_id`, User.name AS `User.name`, User.username AS `User.username`, User.email AS `User.email`, Claim.approved AS `Claim.approved`, Totals.user_rating AS `Review.user_rating`, Totals.user_rating_count AS `Review.user_rating_count`, Totals.user_criteria_rating AS `Review.user_criteria_rating`, Totals.user_criteria_rating_count AS `Review.user_criteria_rating_count`, Totals.user_comment_count AS `Review.review_count`, Totals.editor_rating AS `Review.editor_rating`, Totals.editor_rating_count AS `Review.editor_rating_count`, Totals.editor_criteria_rating AS `Review.editor_criteria_rating`, Totals.editor_criteria_rating_count AS `Review.editor_criteria_rating_count`, Totals.editor_comment_count AS `Review.editor_review_count`, Totals.media_count AS `Listing.media_count`, Totals.video_count AS `Listing.video_count`, Totals.photo_count AS `Listing.photo_count`, Totals.audio_count AS `Listing.audio_count`, Totals.attachment_count AS `Listing.attachment_count`, (Totals.media_count - Totals.media_count_user) AS `Listing.media_count_owner`, (Totals.video_count - Totals.video_count_user) AS `Listing.video_count_owner`, (Totals.photo_count - Totals.photo_count_user) AS `Listing.photo_count_owner`, (Totals.audio_count - Totals.audio_count_user) AS `Listing.audio_count_owner`, (Totals.attachment_count - Totals.attachment_count_user) AS `Listing.attachment_count_owner`, Totals.media_count_user AS `Listing.media_count_user`, Totals.video_count_user AS `Listing.video_count_user`, Totals.photo_count_user AS `Listing.photo_count_user`, Totals.audio_count_user AS `Listing.audio_count_user`, Totals.attachment_count_user AS `Listing.attachment_count_user` FROM #__content AS Listing USE KEY (jr_created) LEFT JOIN #__jreviews_listing_totals AS Totals ON Totals.listing_id = Listing.id AND Totals.extension = 'com_content' LEFT JOIN #__jreviews_content AS Field ON Field.contentid = Listing.id LEFT JOIN #__jreviews_categories AS JreviewsCategory ON JreviewsCategory.id = Listing.catid AND JreviewsCategory.`option` = 'com_content' LEFT JOIN #__categories AS Category ON Category.id = Listing.catid AND Category.extension = 'com_content' LEFT JOIN #__jreviews_directories AS Directory ON Directory.id = JreviewsCategory.dirid LEFT JOIN #__users AS User ON User.id = Listing.created_by LEFT JOIN #__jreviews_claims AS Claim ON Claim.listing_id = Listing.id AND Claim.user_id = Listing.created_by AND Claim.approved = 1 WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( Listing.catid IN (9) AND Listing.state >= 0 AND Listing.access IN ( 1,2,3) ) ORDER BY Listing.created DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you work on the formatting of your question it's pretty unreadable.  Or maybe trim it down a bit.  Are all of those fields really necessary to explain your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As @Gray has said above, welcome to SO. It seems there is a problem with the table, "#__jreviews_listing_totals". If you do Control+F on this page and search for "AS Totals" you'll see where the alias "Totals" has been made to represent that table. Without seeing the structure of that table I can't definitively say why you're getting the error but it seems that the field, "media_count" doesn't exist inside of it.

Comment: I managed to fix the error above by adding the "media_count" into the table structure but I've still got hundreds of errors to go!

Comment: Was this a known issue with upgrading or is this an error that happened only when you upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

The structure for the referenced table should be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__jreviews_listing_totals` (
  `listing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_rating` DECIMAL( 9, 4 ) NOT NULL,
  `user_rating_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_rating_rank` DECIMAL(9,4) NOT NULL,
  `user_criteria_rating` text NOT NULL,
  `user_criteria_rating_count` text NOT NULL,
  `user_comment_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `editor_rating` DECIMAL( 9, 4 ) NOT NULL,
  `editor_rating_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `editor_rating_rank` DECIMAL(9,4) NOT NULL,
  `editor_criteria_rating` text NOT NULL,
  `editor_criteria_rating_count` text NOT NULL,
  `editor_comment_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `media_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `video_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `photo_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `audio_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attachment_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `media_count_user` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `video_count_user` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `photo_count_user` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `audio_count_user` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attachment_count_user` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`listing_id`, `extension`),
  INDEX `user_rating` (  `user_rating` ,  `user_rating_count` ),
  INDEX `editor_rating` (  `editor_rating` ,  `editor_rating_count` ),
  INDEX (  `user_rating_rank`),
  INDEX (  `editor_rating_rank`),
  INDEX (  `user_comment_count` ),
  INDEX (  `media_count` ),
  INDEX (  `video_count` ),
  INDEX (  `photo_count` ),
  INDEX (  `audio_count` ),
  INDEX (  `attachment_count` ),
  INDEX (  `media_count_user` ),
  INDEX (  `video_count_user` ),
  INDEX (  `photo_count_user` ),
  INDEX (  `audio_count_user` ),
  INDEX (  `attachment_count_user` ),
  INDEX `user_editor_photo_counts` (`user_comment_count`,`editor_comment_count`,`photo_count`)
  ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can also find the complete database schema for JReviews in the JReviews component in Joomla or the JReviews plugin folder in WordPress in the jreviews.sql file.

As the developer of [JReviews](https://www.jreviews.com) I can tell you that it is a very well supported solution for both Joomla and WordPress. If you are a client with active support you just need to submit a ticket on our website.