# Joomla JReviews Theme broken when converting Joomla build

Tags: joomla

[Broken JReviews Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5G4t.png)

Upgraded Joomla Build
Migrated DB using the JReviews guide
Long story short using Rating Migrator the page is still broken

Please help!

Comment: Please check this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also its difficult to give support for a paid component without knowing its code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a client with an active support package you just need to submit a ticket on our [JReviews](https://www.jreviews.com) website and we would be happy to take a look. I already told you this on your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302218/joomla-unknown-column-jreviews) and also when you contacted us through Facebook. We haven't heard back from you on our ticket system with your license and site information.